# Formulario con Fechas en Django

Tags: django, formularios, django-models, django-forms

Tengo un modelo con un campo fecha de tipo `DateTimeField`

```
class RegistroGestionAcceso(models.Model):
    ...
    fecha_solicitud = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name='Fecha Solicitud')
    ...
```

En el formulario usando `ModelForm` tengo lo siguiente

```
class DateTimeInput(forms.DateTimeInput):
    input_type = 'datetime-local'

class RegistroForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = RegistroGestionAcceso
        fields = '__all__'
        widgets = {
            ...
            'fecha_solicitud': DateTimeInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            ...
        }
```

Al guardar el formulario me genera error de fecha/hora no válida

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El panel de desarrollo del navegador me muestra lo siguiente

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Nota:** Hice la prueba en el modelo usando por separado la fecha con `DateField` y la hora con `TimeField` y se guarda correctamente, el problema viene cuando uso `DateTimeField`

Intente cambiando el formato del input de varias maneras en el método `__init__` pero sigue arrojando el error

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        
    super(RegistroForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.fields['fecha_solicitud'].input_formats = ['%d/%m/%Y %H:%M']
```

Alguna manera de solucionarlo?? que no sea ingresando la fecha y la hora por separado, ya que son varios campos del formulario en el que uso fechas

Answer (score -1):

lo tengo casi igual a como lo tienes y a mi me funciono sin mayores problemas, te comparto como lo tengo.

Modelo:

```
class Venta(models.Model):
    fecha=models.DateTimeField(auto_now=False)
```

Formulario:

```
class DateTimeInput(forms.DateTimeInput):
    input_type = 'datetime-local'

class FormularioVenta(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model=Venta
        fields=('fecha',)
        
widgets = {
            
            'fecha': DateTimeInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            
        }
```

Html:

```
<form action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" style="color: white;">
  {% csrf_token %}
  {{creaventa.as_p}}

  <input type="submit" value="Crear/Editar" style=" width:150px;">
</form>
```

Comment: <form action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" style="color: white;">
  {% csrf_token %}
  {{creaventa.as_p}}

  <input type="submit" value="Crear/Editar" style=" width:150px;">
</form>

Comment: Hola y bienvenido a [es.so]. Puede serte de interés realizar el [tour] y leer [answer], para que el aporte no sea considerado de baja calidad.

Comment: Escribir código que (en teoría funciona) no creo que sea una respuesta. Si lo sabes, por favor explica por qué se produce el error y enfoca el código en cómo corregirlo.

Answer (score -2):

Puedes agregar código de formato de la siguiente manera en tu modelForm:

```
class RegistroForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.fields['fecha_solicitud'].widget.format = '%d/%m/%Y %H:%M'
```

Comment: Pulsa en [edit] para explicar qué hace este código. Recuerda que otras personas lo verán y probablemente no comprenderán su funcionamiento, además de que _[es.so] no es un repositorio de código_. Lee [answer].

Comment: te recomiendo leer el artículo [Te he votado negativamente porque es solamente código.](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2882/)

Comment: @RuslanLópez Ya se ha editado la respuesta como se indica en el artículo, gracias por la sugerencia. Nunca es tarde para seguir aprendiendo.